# wordpress - get_catgories custom ordering

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am using `get_categories` to show posts in a category in my frontpage, but I want to order categories as i defined,Like:

```
$cat_order = 5,2,4,1,3 //order by category ID
or
$cat_order = cat5,cat2,cat4,cat1,cat3 // order by cat name
```

below is my current code which order cat by `name, ASC`

```
<?php
//for each category, show all posts
$cat_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
   );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'showposts' => -1,
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <article >
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

            <?php the_content(); ?>
          </article>
          <?php
        } // foreach($posts
      } // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to sort this within the query itself. You'll have to sort it yourself once you get the results back. To sort an array by custom criteria, use the [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. Here's an example:

```
$categories = get_categories();
$cat_order  = array(5, 2, 4, 1, 3);

usort($categories, function ($a, $b) {
    return ((int) array_search($a->term_id , $cat_order)) - ((int) array_search($b->term_id , $cat_order));
});
```

If you're sure that all the categories are in your `$cat_order` array, you can forgo the integer casting.

---

**P.S.** If you're using PHP < 5.2, use a named function instead:

```
function sort_categories ($a, $b) {
    return ((int) array_search($a->term_id , $cat_order)) - ((int) array_search($b->term_id , $cat_order));
}

usort($categories, 'sort_categories');
```